# Extract few characters from databinder.eval function

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview named listview1.
I am binding it from database using value of Questiontitle.

```
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="questionlink" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Questiontitle") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

but i just want only a few number of characters from the <%# Eval("Questiontitle") %> value
lets say first 20 characters

how can it be managed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324784/databinder-eval-and-substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aspx:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="questionlink" runat="server" Text='<%# ProcessData(Eval("Questiontitle")) %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

C#

```
protected string ProcessData(obj val)
{
  if(val!=null) {return val.ToString().Length > 20 ? val.ToString().Substring(0,20) + "...." : val.ToString();}
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use substring in EVAL. Instead you use substring in your query or You can use in RowDataBound event of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Check above example on how to do it with SQL

```
select substring ('This is such a long I mean soooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo long question',1,15)as question
```

Result:

```
This is such a
```

[MSDN:SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)